# Affine Subspace of System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Show that the solution-set of a system of m linear equations in n unknowns is an affine subspace of $F^n$. What is its corresponding subspace?

The definition I have of an affine subspace for a subset A of a vector space V is that if A is a translate of a subspace W of V, $A = v_0 + W = (v_0 + w, w \in W)$ and then W is the corresponding subspace to A. How would I find $v_0$ and W here? Or I do not need to find them to show the result, I am stuck on how to solve this problem so any general directions to get me started would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You (should) know that the solution set of a system of linear equations where the right-hand side is 0 is a vector space.

It could help to consider a practical case, say
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
2x-3y+z=4\\
x+2y+z=5
\end{array}
\right.$$
compared to
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
2x-3y+z=0\\
x+2y+z=0
\end{array}
\right.$$
The solutions of the second system form a line through $(0,0,0)$ that is a vector subspace. What about the first?

Comment: the solution set of a nonhomogenous system is an affine space right? how would i use that info to proceed from there--does that directly give me the result?

Comment: since any vector space is an affine space (the other dierction is not true)

Comment: The solutions of the 1st system form an affine space, the underlying vector space is the solution of the homogeneous system. To find by how much it is translated, you just need any solution of the 1st system, you can find it by observation or by trying to solve.

Comment: got it, that is what i meant; thank you for clarifying :) and it is translated by (4,5) plus the underlying vector space if i am correct? if so, how do i generalize this to something with m equations and n unknowns--is it (b1,b2,...bm)+corresponding subapce (which is the underlying subspace of homogenous)?

Comment: btw, what exactly is V here according to my above definition? is it e.g. rationals, reals, complex,etc?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what $V$ is in this argument. I assumed it to be $\mathbb{R}^n$.